# Intellij connect hortonwork spark remotely failed

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-streaming

I have a hortonwork sandbox 2.4 with spark 1.6 set up. Then I create Intellij spark development environment in windows using hdp spark jar and scala 2.10.5. So both spark and scala version are matched between my windows and hdp environment as indicated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34518669/unable-to-connect-to-spark-master). And my Intellij dev environment works with local as Master.
Then I'm trying to connect hdp in windows using

```
val sparkConf = new SparkConf()
      .setAppName("spark-word-count")
      .setMaster("spark://10.33.241.160:7077")
```

And I get below error information and have no clue to resolve it. Please help!

```
6/03/21 16:27:40 INFO SparkUI: Started SparkUI at http://10.33.240.126:4040
16/03/21 16:27:40 INFO AppClient$ClientEndpoint: Connecting to master spark://10.33.241.160:7077...
16/03/21 16:27:41 WARN AppClient$ClientEndpoint: Failed to connect to master 10.33.241.160:7077
java.io.IOException: Failed to connect to /10.33.241.160:7077
    at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:216)
    at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:167)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv.createClient(NettyRpcEnv.scala:200)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Outbox$$anon$1.call(Outbox.scala:187)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Outbox$$anon$1.call(Outbox.scala:183)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information: /10.33.241.160:7077
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:692)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:224)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:289)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:528)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:468)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:382)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:354)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:111)
    ... 1 more
16/03/21 16:28:40 ERROR MapOutputTrackerMaster: Error communicating with MapOutputTracker
java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.tryAcquireSharedNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1325)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryAwait(Promise.scala:208)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.ready(Promise.scala:218)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.result(Promise.scala:223)
    at scala.concurrent.Await$$anonfun$result$1.apply(package.scala:107)
    at scala.concurrent.BlockContext$DefaultBlockContext$.blockOn(BlockContext.scala:53)
    at scala.concurrent.Await$.result(package.scala:107)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.awaitResult(RpcTimeout.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEndpointRef.askWithRetry(RpcEndpointRef.scala:101)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEndpointRef.askWithRetry(RpcEndpointRef.scala:77)
    at org.apache.spark.MapOutputTracker.askTracker(MapOutputTracker.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.MapOutputTracker.sendTracker(MapOutputTracker.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.MapOutputTrackerMaster.stop(MapOutputTracker.scala:462)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.stop(SparkEnv.scala:93)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$stop$12.apply$mcV$sp(SparkContext.scala:1756)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryLogNonFatalError(Utils.scala:1229)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.stop(SparkContext.scala:1755)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.SparkDeploySchedulerBackend.dead(SparkDeploySchedulerBackend.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.client.AppClient$ClientEndpoint.markDead(AppClient.scala:264)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.client.AppClient$ClientEndpoint$$anon$2$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(AppClient.scala:134)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrExit(Utils.scala:1163)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.client.AppClient$ClientEndpoint$$anon$2.run(AppClient.scala:129)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRunAndReset(FutureTask.java:351)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:178)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Comment: can you ping 10.33.240.126? Are spark services up?.

Comment: @KrishnaKalyan I can ping 10.33.240.126. Both my hdp and local intellij environment are working.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I need to setup my hortonworks Spark as master server every time server restart. Then use my intellij dev environment to connect with hdp as slave. Just run ./sbin/start-master.sh in hdp as this [link](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-standalone.html).

Comment: Are you completly sure that is necessary to do that every time? Do you have workaround? I'm using new HDP2.6. and Spark2 and badly need the way to connect my IntelliJ spark app to remote cluster master spark :O